# Preload Texture Atlases Completion Handler not working

Tags: swift, uiimageview, texture-atlas

I have a UIImageView for the user to look at (looks almost like a splash screen) come up so that I can preload my texture atlases.

But it seems that in the completion block, even though I say to 'removefromsuperview' it doesn't do so.

I know that the textures have finished loading because if I tap the screen the UIImageView goes away and my game starts, but it won't go away on its own for some odd reason.

Here is my viewDidLoad inside my GameViewController:

```
//Configure the View
    let skView = view as! SKView

    skView.multipleTouchEnabled = false
    self.view.exclusiveTouch = false

    //Create and Configure the scene
    scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)

    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

    //Load "SPLASH SCREEN"
    let image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "ViewControllerImage")!
    GameViewController.splashView = UIImageView(image: image)
    GameViewController.splashView!.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.bounds.width,self.view.bounds.height)
    self.view.addSubview(GameViewController.splashView!)




SKTextureAtlas.preloadTextureAtlases([GameViewController.diploTextureAtlas,GameViewController.bieberTextureAtlas,GameViewController.skrillexTextureAtlas,GameViewController.sunTextureAtlas], withCompletionHandler: { () -> Void in

        print("Completo")
        GameViewController.splashView?.removeFromSuperview()
        skView.presentScene(self.scene)

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
//Configure the View
    let skView = view as! SKView

    skView.multipleTouchEnabled = false
    self.view.exclusiveTouch = false

    //Create and Configure the scene
    scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)

    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

    //Load "SPLASH SCREEN"
    let image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "ViewControllerImage")!
    GameViewController.splashView = UIImageView(image: image)
    GameViewController.splashView.tag = 666
    GameViewController.splashView!.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.bounds.width,self.view.bounds.height)
    self.view.addSubview(GameViewController.splashView!)




SKTextureAtlas.preloadTextureAtlases([GameViewController.diploTextureAtlas,GameViewController.bieberTextureAtlas,GameViewController.skrillexTextureAtlas,GameViewController.sunTextureAtlas], withCompletionHandler: { () -> Void in

        print("Completo")
        for view in self.view!.subviews {
            if view.tag == 666 {
               view.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
        skView.presentScene(self.scene)

    })
```

You can change for cycle also with:

```
if let viewWithTag = self.view.viewWithTag(666) {
        viewWithTag.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: Ah no this didn't seem to work. In order to remove the splash view from the screen, i still need to tap the screen for some reason, for some reason it doesn't go away after the textures load. When i tap to get rid of the splash screen, this also starts my game, it is as if the splash view is on my GameScene. Very odd